# "Error: ls -l: command not found" How to fix?

Tags: bash

```
function x()
{
    cd "path"
    items=(*)
    items=$("ls -l")

      for((i=0;i<${#items};i++));
        do
            echo ${items[$i]} | cat  ${items[$i]}.*| head
        done
}
x
```

I am trying to list "head" for each file in the directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotes around the command:

```
items=$(ls -l)
```

But what's wrong with just:

```
head *.*
```

This get the head of all files.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use backticks for system commands.

Try the following

```
       items=`ls -l`
```

EDITED to fix the error

Comment: This doesn't even work. Back ticks can be used but without the brackets: `items=\`ls -l\``.

Answer (score 0):

commands in quotes are interpreted as a whole command. just remove the quotes from

```
$("ls -l")
```

and the command will be recognized correctly (ls with option -l, not a "ls -l" command)